# I can see the application behind the current one (Debian)

Tags: gnome

Whenever I open an application, I am able to see what is behind it (could be google chrome or my desktop) from the top of the application.

For instance, when I am using Pycharm and have a video opened in full screen on google I can see some parts of the video between the top bar and the application - [image: like this]

I use Debian buster with Gnome DE and WM[image]

Comment: I haven't used Gnome in years, but there used to be a setting somewhere in `dconf` about the padding used for the top bar. You could try searching in `dconf-editor`.